# remove image in wordpress admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress, image, hyperlink

I want to add `<a>` tag to `<i>` that will remove an image when I press on the icon.
Here is a code to WP gallery in this plugin:

```
<# if ( data.values[0] ) { #>
    <div class="main_image">
        <div class="main_image_droppable">
            <div class="inner">
                <div class="inner-bordered">
                    <i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i>
                </div>
                <span>{{ data.l10n.drop }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="{{data.values[0].src}}" />
    </div>
    <div class="stm_mini_thumbs">
        <# _.each( data.values, function( img, id) { #>
            <div class="thumbs">
                <div class="inner">
                    <img src="{{img.thumb}}" />
                    <div class="inner-hover">
                  /* <a> tag should be here */      <i class="fa fa-remove" data-delete="{{id}}"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-arrows"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <# } ) #>
    </div>
<# } else { #>
    <div class="butterbean-placeholder">{{ data.l10n.placeholder }}</div>
<# } #>
```

I want to delete it without reloading the page. I don't know how to do this at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a little of JS/jQuery, just wrap the `i` tag inside an `a` tag with specific class:

```
<a href="#" class="image-remove-btn"><i class="fa fa-remove" data-delete="{{id}}"></i></a>
```

And use jQuery to listen to click event to remove the image

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.image-remove-btn', function (e) {
        $(this).closest('.thumbs').remove();
    });
});
```

Make sure the `thumbs` class in `$(this).closest('.thumbs')` is the correct class for the image container.

Comment: I get this error when I'm pressing on the icon `GET chrome-extension://pbflmbcnfhlmkailckphakbhahkifapg/content/styles.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: This error is not related to any of the code above, it relates to an extension you have installed on your browser

Comment: In opera I have exactly same problem and when I press the icon, it's just brings me to the top of page and nothing is deleted

Comment: Thanks a lot, You are genius!

Comment: Welcome, happy to help :)

Comment: By the way, do you know how to make it with jquery.ajax with POST method. Because images remove only in current DOM html and I want to remove them from post. I add `data-id` to every `img`

Comment: Checkout the answer here, it might help you https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/212456/delete-post-image-attachments-with-jquery-from-the-front-end